# Gaussian RBF Visualization in Python

Tags: python, mapping, svm

It is some days that I am trying to visualize the so-called kernel trick resulting from a RBF kernel transformation in a SVC model. Basically, I am trying to map a 2D space to a 3D space in order to let the viewer see how the kernel trick adds a dimension in order to linearly separate the space between two classes.

Following sklearn examples, I managed to plot a 2D example of the trick. However, I feel it is not enough to really grasp what it is happening behind the scences.

Below is what I managed to plot:

[image]

I would like to plot the same data on a three dimensional space, representing also the plane that splits the space between the two classes.
I am not asking for the actual code here. Rather, I would like to understand what goes on the axis for the third dimension. Indeed, I think that such axis should be equal to `exp(-gamma||x-y||^2)`. However, due to my poor vector algebra skills, I do not know how to compute it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

***UPDATE***

The following allowed me to build a new matrix for a 3D plot:

```
def feature_map_2(X):  
    return np.asarray((X[:,0], X[:,1], np.exp( -gam*(( X[:,0]**2 + X[:,1]**2 -2*X[:,0]*X[:,1]))))).T

Z = feature_map_2(X)
```

Where `gam = 1/n_features`

Then, I computed the boundary as follows:

```
#SVM 
clf = svm.NuSVC(kernel = 'linear', nu=0.5)
clf.fit(Z, y) 


w = clf.coef_.flatten()
b = clf.intercept_.flatten()

# create x,y
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-6,6), np.linspace(-2,2))

# calculate corresponding z
boundary = lambda xx, yy: (-w[0] * xx - w[1] * yy - b) * 1. /w[2]
```

However, results differ from what one might have expected looking at the 2D plot.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean SVM model?

https://jgreitemann.github.io/svm-demo

Visualizing 3D may be difficult because you will need to project to the screen bringing again to a 2D image.

To find the plane in the 3D space you simply apply your kernel to make your classes linearly separable and then apply a
[Linear SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Linear_SVM)

The equation `w' x - b = 0` expressed in terms of scalars as `w[0] * x[0] + w[1] * x[1] + w[2] * x[2] - b = 0`, can be made parametric by choosing element of x (with non-zero coefficient). For instance if `w[2] != 0` you can write the plane as.

(U, V, (b - w[0] * U - w[1] * V) / w[2])

And this may be used in common surface plot functions, for instance in python it would be like this

```py
U, V = meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 100), np.linspace(-1, 1, 100))
plt.pcolormesh(U, V, (b - w[0] * U - w[1] * V) / w[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks man! Somehow, I managed to build a three dimensional plot. What I did was first centering the points (by subtracting the mean) and then building a new n*3 matrix that was identical to the original n*2 matrix, but with a third column that equalled ```||x0-x1||^2 = ||x0||^2 - 2<x0, x1> + ||x1||^2``` See the updated post for the code.